# Datatable showing :DataTables warning: table id=userdetails - Requested unknown parameter '1' for row 0, column 1

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, datatable

I am using datatable plugin in my project but it showing me some warning message

> DataTables warning: table id=userdetails - Requested unknown parameter
>   '1' for row 0, column 1. For more information about this error, please
>   see http://datatables.net/tn/4

code is:
Html code:

```
<table id="userdetails">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td>User Login</td>
            <td>User NiceName</td>
            <td>Email</td>
            <td>Register Date</td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
<table>
```

ajax call

```
<script>
    jQuery.ajax({
        type : 'POST',
        data : {tableName:table_name},
        url: '<?php echo plugins_url() . '/pagination/ajaxResponse.php'; ?>',
        success: function(data){
            jQuery("#userdetails").dataTable({
                    data:data,
                    colums:[
                        {'data':'user_login'},
                        {'data': 'user_nicename'},
                        {'data': 'user_email'},
                        {'data': 'user_registered'},
                    ]
                })
        }
    })

</script>
```

server code:

```
$result = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT user_login,user_nicename,user_email,user_registered from ".$_POST['tableName']);
        echo json_encode($result);
```

responce:
[image]
I am unable to figure out issue

Comment: Can you add your html also.

Comment: @Rushee  updated question

Comment: Uh, `colums` should be spelled `columns`? That is probably why DataTables is derping out, because it has no column structure to map the incoming data to.

Comment: As you are using the Javascript sourced data, you can do this way also 
https://jsfiddle.net/7mhtkmpv/1/ . Hope this help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though you are sending data in JSON format from PHP file, you need to accept it as JSON in AJAX call.

You need to do 2 modifications:

- add **dataType:'json',** to your AJAX call,
- Change 'colums' to 'columns' as suggested by @Terry

**i.e. your AJAX call should look like:**

```
    <script>
    jQuery.ajax({
        type : 'POST',
        data : {tableName:table_name},
        dataType:'json',
        url: '<?php echo plugins_url() . '/pagination/ajaxResponse.php'; ?>',
        success: function(data){
            jQuery("#userdetails").dataTable({
                    data:data,
                    columns:[
                        {'data':'user_login'},
                        {'data': 'user_nicename'},
                        {'data': 'user_email'},
                        {'data': 'user_registered'},
                    ]
                })
        }
    })

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Insert this code JS ajax to add error handle. Also get a correct json from entityframework.

```
jQuery.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'json',
    url: 'https://localhost:44361/api/car',
    success: function (data) {
        var data = jQuery.parseJSON(data); 
        console.log(data);
        jQuery("#tableAPI").dataTable({
            data: data,
            columns: [
                { 'data': 'vin' },
                { 'data': 'marca' },
                { 'data': 'tipo' },
                { 'data': 'fechaEmsablado' }
            ]
        })
    },
    error: function(e,message){
        jQuery("#tableAPI").dataTable({

        }),
        alert(message);
    }

})
```